# If Φ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ) , show that Φ,¬ϕ and Φ, ψ are both inconsistent.

Tags: propositional-calculus

So far I have shown that Φ, ψ is inconsistent:

If Φ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ) then Φ, ψ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ)

By the axiom ψ→ϕ→ψ and Modus Ponens, Φ, ψ⊢ϕ→ψ.

So Φ, ψ is inconsistent.

Could anyone help me to prove that Φ,¬ϕ is inconsistent?

Comment: I do not get the gist of your question: what is $\Phi$, $\phi$ and $\psi$? Which conditions hold for them? $\Phi,\psi\vdash\lnot(\phi\to\psi)$ is the only condition you have assumed?

Comment: I missed a step here. If Φ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ) then Φ, ψ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ).

Comment: Hint: $\Phi\vdash \phi\land \lnot\psi$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think i know what you are trying to tell me. But i'm looking for a proof using only ¬ and →.

Comment: @mdryizk If you're looking for a proof in a particular formal system you should indicate this in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same reasoning you used for the first part, $$ \Phi,\lnot\phi \vdash \lnot \psi \to \lnot \phi.$$ By the contrapositive axiom (theorem? you haven't told us which system you are using... it seems clear that it's Hilbert style from context, but there are several commonly used versions of Axiom 3), $$ \Phi,\lnot \phi\vdash (\lnot\psi\to \lnot \phi)\to(\phi\to \psi), $$ so by MP $$\Phi,\lnot \phi\vdash \phi\to\psi $$